# Createa a random 5x5 board of letters

Tags: java, arrays, random

For the life of me I can't figure out why my code is simply printing out in a straight line, rather than 5x5.  I know it's a simple solution but I've been coding different programs for days and I can't figure this out at all right now, any help is appreciated!

import java.util.Random;
public class RandomWordGame {

```
private static char[][] letterBoard = new char[5][5];
private static Random r = new Random();

private static char[][] createBoard()
{
    for (int i=0; i<letterBoard.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<letterBoard[i].length; j++)
        {
            letterBoard[i][j] = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            System.out.print(letterBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return letterBoard;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    letterBoard = createBoard();
}
```

}

Comment: Print a newline after inner loop if I understood your question!

Comment: Put a System.out.println(); after the inner for loop.

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel dumb 

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a newline after the inner loop

```
for (int i=0; i<letterBoard.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<letterBoard[i].length; j++) {
        letterBoard[i][j] = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        System.out.print(letterBoard[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
return letterBoard;
```